# New Android Studio + New project - Failed to resolve

Tags: android-studio

I am trying to make my first Android App.
Downloaded and installed the Android Studio, and followed the tutorial to start a new simple "Hello world" app, just to get started, and see that everything works.
But it does not.
I have not written one single line of code myself, so the source is completely generated by Android Studio itself.

I get this error:
Failed to resolve: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+

and

Failed to resolve: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2

When creating the project, I choose API level 15.

In the SDK manager, I have both API level 15 and 25 installed ( I think 25 was default installed, and I have installed API 15 or vice versa).

I have googled a lot, and tried different SDK's, but always the same error. No matter what versions I try to use, it fails with the same message.

Why doesn't the very first tutorial work?
I am a bit confused, if it is so difficult to make the first "Hello world" app :0)

[Screenshor of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WScqr.jpg)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Go to SDK and update Constraint layout in SDK tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to File -> Settings -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle and then uncheck **Offline** and then resync the project and rebuild even if all of the above doesn't work try reinstalling the whole setup

Comment: Thanks for fast response!
But this is already unchecked.
Here: File->Settings->Build, Execution, Deployment-> Gradle...

Comment: @Kaare post your build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

@Rahul Kumar

My build.gradle below.
Project is created using API 15 as minimum.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "dk.surlution.app3"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Comment: try adding this as a dependency

    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'

Comment: have you installed support repository through android sdk manager

Comment: Tried the ":25.1.0" version, but same problem.
It seems that anything a write as dependency, makes this error.

Support repository is installed. This was done by default, I did not have to do it.

Comment: Yes, I can see in SDK Manager: Android SDK->SDK Tool  that "Support Repository" is installed. There are four lines, and Android Support Repository is installed version 44.0.0

Comment: check whether "Android SDK Build-tools", "Android SDK Platform-tools" corresponding to your library version are installed

Comment: "Android SDK Build-tools" version is not present in the SDK Manager. The field is empty. It just says "Installed".
"Android SDK Platform-tools" is version 25.0.3

Comment: it should be there in tools and what about google repository is it installed
check this image it should be like this http://imgur.com/a/kX4xr

Comment: Cant see your picture.
I have posted a screenshot of my Tools in a new answer

Comment: try setting the version to 25.0.3

Answer (score 0):

@Rahul

Here is the Screenshot of my Tools installed.
Google Repository installed too

[Screenshot of Tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AT2y4.jpg)

Comment: Hmmmm, is this part of the Android Studio?
I can't find out how this is installed as a standalone program. Every link I find just links to the Android Studio installation.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/images/sdk-manager-tools_2-0_2x.jpg
check this image it has a option in bottom left for opening sdk manager

Comment: I don't have that option in my SDK Manager...
Should it have been installed with my standard Android Studio installer?
Maybe this is the essential of my problem, as it seems like something is totally wrong from the beginning ?

Comment: Yes it should have been try reinstalling from scratch

Comment: OK, now it works !
Uninstalled Android Studio, and reinstalled.
Only thing I did was change the SDK folder to another one than the installer suggested.
Now SDK is installed in C:\abc\Android_SDK
During first startup, I had to tell Android Studio the right folder.

If this did the trick, I don't know, but I am happy now, and have my first app running on my phone. Now the fun part starts :0)

Thanks ALOT for your help and time, Rahul !!!

Comment: You can delete all the irrelevant answers now and i have updated the answer and you can accept it